# ng-model saving with a recursive display

Tags: angularjs

**Setup**

I have a frontend that displays a JSON. One can edit the values in the JSON via an ng-model `textarea` with a save button.

It does this by recursively calling an object like this:

In tree-object-edit.html:

```
...
<h4 class="capitalize">{{ item_key }}:  </h4>
<textarea rows="2" cols="60" ng-model="item"></textarea>
<div ng-if="item.properties">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(item_key, item) in item.properties" ng-include="'html/tree-object.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is called by this my-definition.html

```
        <form name="form"
          role="form"
          novalidate
          class="ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-minlength"
          ng-controller="MyDefinitionDetailController">

            <h4>My Definition Edit: {{myDefinition.name}}</h4>
            <ul ng-repeat="(item_key,item) in myDefinition" ng-include="'html/tree-object-edit.html'"></ul>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="create()">
                &nbsp;<span>Save</span>
            </button>

        </form>
```

My my-defintion-detail.controller.js contains

```
    $scope.create = function () {
        MyDefinition.save($scope.myDefinition,
            function () {
            });
    };
```

**Problem**

Clicking save does not save the `myDefintion` because `myDefiniton` has not been changed. Only `item` has been changed.

**Question**

Is there a way to make the `myDefiniton` change when the `item` "within it" changes?

**UPDATE 1**

I have found that:

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="60" ng-model="myDefinition[item_key]"></textarea>
```

Does work for the first level of the recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly noted, that `ng-model="myDefinition[item_key]"`(`parent[key]` at my example) works, - changes will reflect into desired model, if you will make them on property level not on direct value. So, besides passing `value` and `key` to nested template, you also should pass `parent` object, that way chain of references from actual value to "head" will be created:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = {
      identity: {
        name: 'Max',
        surName:'Smith',
      },
      birthDay: {
        year: 1990,
        month: 2,
        day: {
          weekDay: 'friday',
          number: '13'
        }
      },
      firstLevel: 'abc'
    }
    $scope.isObject = function(value){
      return angular.isObject(value);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="template">        
        {{key}}
        <ul ng-init='temp=value'>
            <input ng-if='!isObject(value)' type='text' ng-model='parent[key]'/>
            <li ng-if='isObject(temp)' ng-repeat='(key, value) in temp' ng-init='parent=temp' ng-include="'template'"></li>                            
        </ul>
    </script>

    <ul ng-init='parent=value'>
        <li ng-repeat='(key, value) in value' ng-include="'template'"></li>                            
    </ul>
    {{value | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a perhaps more elegant solution: (Note if you update angular recursive directives also becomes a thing)

```js
angular.module('app', ['dotjem.angular.tree']).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = {
      identity: {
        name: 'Max',
        surName:'Smith',
      },
      birthDay: {
        year: 1990,
        month: 2,
        day: {
          weekDay: 'friday',
          number: '13'
        }
      },
      firstLevel: 'abc'
    }
    $scope.isObject = function(value){
      return angular.isObject(value);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/dotJEM/angular-tree-bower/master/dotjem-angular-tree.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
    <ul dx-start-with="value as parent">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in parent">
            {{key}}
            <input ng-if="!isObject(value)" type="text" ng-model="parent[key]"/>
            <ul ng-if="isObject(value)" dx-connect="value"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <pre>{{value | json}}
    </pre>
</div>
```